# mysql query if else not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my query i want to add  another condition

```
if((select ShowMan from preferences where `UserId`='92') == true )
 then users.gender !='female'
```

here is my full query

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE users.id != '92' AND

        users.id NOT IN (SELECT matched_user_id
                               FROM `user_matchs`
                               WHERE user_id = '92'
                              )
and
        users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                               FROM `user_matchs`
                               WHERE matched_user_id = '92'
                         AND status = 'friend'
                              ) 

and if((select ShowMan from preferences where `UserId`='92') == true ) 
then users.gender !='female'
```

my logic isifuser 92 ShowMan value is true then add a condition users.gender !='female'
if  ShowMan value is false then add a condition users.gender !='male'

Comment: You can only use the [expression (ternary operator) variety](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) of `IF` in queries. `IF .. THEN .. ELSE` can only be used in functions/triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the last part to this work :

```
and ((NOT (select ShowMan from preferences where `UserId`='92')) OR (users.gender !='female'))
```

or this for a full query

```
SELECT 'users'.*
FROM `users`
JOIN preferences ON `UserID` = users.id
WHERE users.id != '92' AND
  users.id NOT IN (SELECT matched_user_id
                   FROM `user_matchs`
                   WHERE user_id = users.id
                  )
AND   users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                   FROM `user_matchs`
                   WHERE matched_user_id = users.id
                   AND status = 'friend'
                  ) 
AND ((NOT `preferences`.`ShowMan`) OR (users.gender !='female'))
```